# Copiar archivos de una carpeta a otra con Python

Tags: python

El ejercicio me pide que copie todos los archivos de una carpeta dada por el usuario a otra carpeta también dada por el usuario, tengo esto pero no me sale:

```
import os
import shutil

pathCarpeta=input('escribe el path de una carpeta')

pathCarpeta2=input('escribe el path de otra carpeta')

if not os.path.isdir(pathCarpeta):
    print('la primera carpeta no existe')
elif not os.path.isdir(pathCarpeta2):
    print('la segunda carpeta no existe')



else:
    contenidos=os.listdir(pathCarpeta)
    for elemento in contenidos:
        shutil.copy(elemento, pathCarpeta2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Debes tener en cuenta que el módulo shutil tiene 2 métodos para copiar [shutil.copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) y [shutil.copy2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2). El primero copia sin preservar los metadatos, o sea, la fecha de modificación o creación del archivo. El segundo si copia todo. Usas uno u otro dependiendo de qué tan importante es mantener esa información.

En tu código quizás esto es opcional, pero no en producción: Aunque existan los directorios de origen y destino, eso no garantiza que se va a poder copiar la información. Si el directorio de destino no tiene permisos de escritura para el script, va a fallar la ejecución del script.

Adicional, creo que en el caso de `copy()`, no es necesario especificar el nombre de destino del archivo, sin embargo es buena práctica hacerlo, ya que en el caso de `move()` si es obligatorio hacerlo y sería muy fácil de cambiar el código de un caso al otro.

Entonces, dentro del bloque `else` iría algo así:

```
contenidos=os.listdir(pathCarpeta)
for elemento in contenidos:
    try:
        print(f"Copiando {elemento} --> {pathCarpeta2} ... ", end="")
        src = os.path.join(pathCarpeta, elemento) # origen
        dst = os.path.join(pathCarpeta2, elemento) # destino
        shutil.copy(src, dst)
        print("Correcto")
    except:
        print("Falló")
        print("Error, no se pudo copiar el archivo. Verifique los permisos de escritura")
```

Comment: Buen script, lo he usado cambiando los print por un logger. Muchas gracias,

Answer (score 0):

En el bucle for abajo de todo, la variable `elemento` no incluye el primer path que ingresó el usuario. Este es el código revisado:

```
import os
import shutil

pathCarpeta=input('escribe el path de una carpeta')

pathCarpeta2=input('escribe el path de otra carpeta')

if not os.path.isdir(pathCarpeta):
    print('la primera carpeta no existe')
elif not os.path.isdir(pathCarpeta2):
    print('la segunda carpeta no existe')



else:
    contenidos=os.listdir(pathCarpeta)
    for elemento in contenidos:
        #aqui está la diferencia con respecto al original
        shutil.copy(pathCarpeta+"/"+elemento, pathCarpeta2)
```